# A technique for realistic image generation

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx, textures, texture-mapping

We are building a web based application to design custom shirts. It will have the same functionality as http://www.blanklabel.com/Products/Shirt

Both applications, based on visitor's selections, use pre-generated image slices to display the custom shirt image.

What I wonder is how these slices are generated. Manually by a graphics designer using a graphics or modelling tool(Photoshop/3DSMax etc.) or programmatically using a technique like texture mapping on a 3D model?

Is it possible to achieve realistic results like the ones in [blanklabel.com](http://www.blanklabel.com/Products/Shirt) using a programmatic technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a guess, but I would create the shirt (or rather the shirt's components) in a modelling application (Blender, 3ds max, Maya, etc) and set all the UV mapping that way.  Then when a user makes a selection, the image is rendered through a game engine (the shadows can be baked as there is no lighting or camera movement) on your servers and then pushed to the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate programmatically photorealistic fabrics, there are a couple papers about that, and in particular the very recent papers:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/ctcloth/
and
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~srm/publications/TOG12-cloth.html
However, they are computationnally expensive (you wouldn't get realtime results to show your clients), so you'd better render these fabrics offline - or alternatively take good quality close-up pictures.

You might also want to hack a spatialy varying BRDF model with some Phong lobes and a texture to control the lobes... but I am not sure this would really look great. The result would highly depend on the artist who will manually tune the parameters so that it looks like the actual fabrics.